Column date and time + add selected time

I have a column with date and time
I have a column with selection of duration minutes  (30/60/90/120)
I want a column where the time is posted with the extra minutes added.

Example:

01/01/2025  13:00
selected duration= 90
showed time in calculated column  14:30

Thanks already for the help.

Try using formula like: = [DateTimeColumn] + [ExtraMinutesColumn]/(24*60). Let me know if it works for you.

What is the column/data type of your column which has extra minutes (30/60/90/120)?

Try using calculated column formula like this:
=[DateTimeColumn] + [ExtraMinutesColumn]/(24*60)

Where "ExtraMinutesColumn" is a "Number" type column.
Column Settings:

Output:

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


If you are using single line of text or choice column for extra minutes, you can try using formula like:
=[DateTimeColumn] + Value([ExtraMinutesChoice])/(24*60)

